# Regular Expression inside filtering in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, filtering

I'm, trying to change when user put

```
color*red
```

And user want to search inside:

```
the color is red
the color is blue
```

I change `*` by `(\W|\w|\s)*` for use it in a regexp inside filtering of Django.

```
NameItem=NameItem.replace("*","(\W|\w|\s)*")

ItemsSelected=Items.objects.filter(Name__iregex=NameItem)
```

But It never give me results.

Any Idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533958/efficient-django-queryset-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make `"(\W|\w|\s)*"` a raw string. On the other hand, I don't know why you use that instead of just `".*"`.

Comment: It's working fine with you change `.*`.