# How to make django queryset ignoring white space

Tags: django

There's some stored in db. the column data can include one more white space like below.

```
Printer
-----------------------------------
   No   |  name      |   data   
-----------------------------------
    1   | 3D Printer | 1
    2   | 3d printer | 21
    3   | 3dPrinter  | 3
```

I want to select all of '3d printer'.

Tell me the way for this.

Comment: @RetoAebersold Printer.objects.filter(name in ['3D Printer','3d printer', ...] is what I want

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1556210/3945375 I don't know if it's still working. Please give a feedback if it does.

Answer (score 7):

You can do like:

```
Printer.objects.extra(where=["LOWER(REPLACE(name,' ','')) = '3dprinter'"])
```

The obove query will first remove any space in the name and then make it lower case, next compare it with **3dprinter**

Since all space in name is removed including the one after **3d**, we need to compare name with just **3dprinter**

Answer (score 1):

I guess django doesn't support SQL `REPLACE` option for strings. But you can use raw sql. Here is Django doc regarding the same: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/

And here is raw SQL query for ignoring whitespaces [Query that ignore the spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709929/query-that-ignore-the-spaces)

In my opinion you should add another column in your table `slug-name` which will stored name without whitespaces. This way you can easily use Django ORM on your table.